# Laravel 5.6 limited login attempt does not work (Throttles Logins)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to ask something why my throttles Logins in Laravel 5.6 does not work, already see the documentation from laravel, here is the code

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Alert;
use App\Http\Controllers\Website\Controller;
use App\Model\User;
use App\Model\Sessions;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
     */

    use AuthenticatesUsers {
        redirectPath as laravelRedirectPath;
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/login');
    }

    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function redirectPath()
    {
        // Do your logic to flash data to session...
        Alert::info('You have been successfully logged in!');

        // Return the results of the method we are overriding that we aliased.
        return $this->laravelRedirectPath();
    }
}
```

auth for login i just use from laravel, I already change in throttleslogins.php

```html
protected function hasTooManyLoginAttempts(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->limiter()->tooManyAttempts(
            $this->throttleKey($request), 5, 3
        );
    }
```

but it only shows "These credentials do not match our records" after 5 attempts. Is there anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: What are you saying is wrong here? The `5` in your above code represents how many attempts before the lockout hits, and the `3` is how many minutes they're locked out for

Comment: after i try to log with wrong password 5 times, it should be blocked for 3 minutes right ? but when i try again the error show "These credentials do not match our records" not "Too many login attempts, try in 180 seconds @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.

Comment: yeah, i stuck in there @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Are you sure the trait is being used?

Comment: i'm sure the trait is being used @Ohgodwhy because is already called in AuthenticatesUsers

Comment: From what you are saying throttling works, but wrong error is presented. Check if throttling properly implemented in your laravel installation. I would check Middlewares defined on your routes, then check throttling settings in your app/Http/Kernel.php.

Comment: already check that, but still have no clue the error doesn't show @Bart

Comment: Try removing Middleware from your construct function, cause it seems to be double declared, if you have it in your route declaration already...